# Expo screen not loading images after I put it in visual studio code

Tags: react-native, image

Everytime I try to load an image into my project, it doesn't show in expo. It shows up as blank when I check the expo screen for my image. I tried multiple times but the image is not loading on the screen. I imported the image and even typed in the call function properly. My code is:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
    return (
         <View>
            <Image source = {require('./assets/logo1.png')}
            style={styles.callText}></Image>
            
            
            <Text style={styles.ligmaText}>Viral</Text>
            <Text style ={styles.fontText}>Forgot Password?</Text>
            <Text style ={styles.baseText}>Don't have an account? <Button title = "Register Now"></Button></Text>
            <Text>Google</Text> 
            <Text>Facebook</Text>


            <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>

    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  baseText: {
     flex: 2,
     marginTop: 0,
     alignItems: 'strech',

     
     
     
  },
  fontText: {
     flex: 10,
      marginTop: 50,
      textAlign: 'right',


  },
  ligmaText: {
     flex: 3,
     fontSize: 22,
     


  },
  callText: {
     flex: 10,
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you try giving fixed width and height to check that the issue is not the style?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure Image tags are self closing

```
<Image/>
```

Comment: still didn't work the expo screen doesn't show the image.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image, i.e. give image height and width in your styles.
Read here: [Image - Expo Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/react-native/image)